# Support for auto-refresh Access Tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, paw-app

So I just started using Paw to replace Soap UI on my new MBP. And for the most parts it looks like it is much easier to work with.

For the solution I am working on the support for OAuth2 is a real plus. But compared to Soap UI there is one thing that Paw does not quite do as well in this regard. I cannot find any options to auto-refresh access tokens.

Is that a feature that is planned. And if not, could you please consider it?

Comment: Sorry for late answer @ Kristoffer. No, auto-refresh isn't supported yet. How often does token expire? In this case you would like to automatically refresh and get a new token?

Comment: We currently expire our access tokens after 10 minutes. And yeah. It would be nice to have support for auto-refresh for this scenario so I don't have to constantly go though the login page when I test stuff. In an ideal world it should be optional to auto-refresh. Another option could be to simply have a refresh button. But for most scenarios the auto option is likely better.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I'll add that to our feature todo list! I'm sure that would be useful for many.

Comment: Cool. I look forward to it ;)

Comment: Want to chime in and say that I also think this would be an amazingly useful feature.

Comment: I too would love this feature. Any idea what the eta is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature appears to have arrived in Paw 2.3.

As can be seen in the release notes: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/updates/2.3